# GAE entity relationships: ancestor vs. reference prop. vs. list of keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a GAE Python app for running elections.  I have an Election entity for each election.  Each election will have around 2-20 candidates and I have a Candidate entity for each Candidate.

I'm considering three different options for modeling the entity relationship:

1. Having the the Election be an ancestor of each Candidate.
2. Adding a reference property to the Candidate that refers to the Election.
3. Adding a list property to the Election that contains a list of Candidate keys.

Since the number of candidates is relatively small, it seems that all could work.  I'm currently doing the first option since I'm using the high-rep data store and I want strong consistency.

For my election app, what are the pros and cons for each of the three options above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your write rate and the number of entities are both low, any of these approaches should work fine. The best one depends on how you access it. If you need to update multiple entities in a transaction, use entity groups (eg, ancestors). If you need a natural ordering of candidates in an election, the list property provides that. Otherwise, a reference from candidate to election is the most natural choice.

Or, you could use [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) and embed your candidate entities in your election entity.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense.  NDB looks interesting too.

Comment: Let's say that the candidates have a natural ordering and I want to update multiple entities in a transaction.  Any reason to not have an ancestor relationship *and* store the candidate entities in a list property?

Comment: @Jeff Sure, that would work. If the ordering can be expressed with a sort key, though, you should probably use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I assume a candidate may take part in more than one election and an election will have more than one candidates.
This is a M2M relationship, and the only efficient way to implement it is to use Listfields in App Engine.

You can try to use reference properties if you don't mind having multiple entities for a candidate if he ever takes part in more than one election.

Another tip:
Keeping datastore write limits in mind (5/sec), instead of every "vote" action updating the counter for that candidate, you can either use [sharded counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) or create new tasks that run in a [taskqueue with 5 tasks/sec upper limit](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#Queue_Definitions).

Comment: I'm not allowing a candidate to take part in more than one election.  If this happens, I will have two candidate objects.  I'm also not using counters to update counts since the voting uses ranked ballots.  Instead, I periodically gather all the votes to count them up.  Also, votes are all standalone entities so I don't have to worry about write limits.